# Access form values in symfony2 where fields were added by jquery

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have a quite simple problem, I have a form generated by symfony and mapped to object but on form submit there is an action of jquery which appends few fields to the form. How can I access these values in symfony? I don't see it in raw $_POST array, it's not in $request value. thanks

Comment: hard to tell if you dont provide the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your request variables, using symfony 2.3, like this:

var_dump($this->getRequest->request->all);